# chef-server-ctl reconfigure is failing

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install the chef server in OpenSUSE subsystem in Windows. The installation is successful but while doing

```
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

I am getting the following error

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CannotDetermineNodeName: Unable to determine node name: configure node_name or configure the system's hostname and fqdn
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not support WSL, or Windows at all for Chef Server. You’ll need to use an actual VM. WSL is advancing quickly but it’s definitely not yet to a point where it can run Chef Server safely.